# How to pass parameter in constructor?

Tags: angular

I have an abstract class:

```
export abstract class SidebarCreator {
    public abstract factoryMethod(): SidebarMenu;
}
```

And realization:

```
export class ApplicationSidebarCreator extends SidebarCreator {
    constructor(private application: IApplication) {
        super();
    }
}
```

Inside component I use it:

```
@Component({
   providers: [{ provide: SidebarCreator, useClass: ApplicationSidebarCreator }]
})

  @Input() application: IApplication;
```

How to do pass variable `application` inside component to constructor of `ApplicationSidebarCreator`?

Comment: Why do you need to pass it in to the constructor only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you designed is possible. `application` is a property on input which can change now and then. I think you will need to implement a `setApplication` method within the service and call it when `application` input changes.

```
export class ApplicationSidebarCreator extends SidebarCreator {
    private application: IApplication

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    setApplication(application: IApplication) {
      this.application = application;
    }
}
```

```
@Component({
   providers: [{ provide: SidebarCreator, useClass: ApplicationSidebarCreator }]
})

  @Input() application: IApplication;

  constructor(private sidebarCreator: SidebarCreator) { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['application']) {
      this.sidecarCreator.setApplication(changes['application'].currentValue);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, why I get this error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(OrdersExecutionModule)[ApplicationSidebarCreator -> ApplicationSidebarCreator -> ApplicationSidebarCreator -> ApplicationSidebarCreator]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ApplicationSidebarCreator!`?

Comment: I use     `providers: [ApplicationSidebarCreator],` `constructor(private applicationSidebarCreator: ApplicationSidebarCreator) {}`

Comment: @Natalie I think we should define it as Injectable `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})export class ApplicationSidebarCreator extends SidebarCreator {}`